# ASP.NET How can I use my class in Page_Load of my aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How can I use my class in Page_Load of my aspx.cs file and why can`t I use it at the moment ?
I added my namespace in my aspx.cx but give me error.

My class is:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
        {
            int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
            if (diff < 0)
            {
                diff += 7;
            }
            return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
        }
    }
```

In my aspx file it looks like following

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="VacationDays.Default" uiCulture="sv" %>
 <% using VacationDays; %>
```

I get error message:

> 'VacationDays' is a namespace but is used like a variable

I would appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code behind i.e. `mypage.aspx.cs`, use

```
using VacationDays;
```

In `mypage.aspx` (as mentioned by Garbriel Luci)

```
<%@ Import namespace="VacationDays" %>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of a `using` statement in an aspx file is different. Try this:

```
<%@ Import namespace="VacationDays" %>
```